# how to make RTSP server at android phone?

Tags: java, android, rtsp

I want send streaming video from android phone to computer server on RTSP.

the server is coded using java.

how can I do that?

Answer (score 9):

RTSP is just a streaming protocal which only includes information about a stream and no data. you can use it as a "tunnel" for data streams (e.g. RTP). you can use RTSP as a tcp connection to support your udp stream. so necessary data can't get lost.

here is a simple example of a RTSP server-client communication: [Streaming Video with RTSP and RTP](http://www.cs.umbc.edu/~pmundur/courses/CMSC691C/lab5-kurose-ross.html).
there are only the basics of the connection (communication) at this exercise and it's for a java application, so you have to modify it a little bit.

to get some more information about the RTSP connection and the sdp file check out the [RFC2326 - RTSP](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2326.txt) and the [RFC4566 - SDP](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4566.txt)

to stream data from your android device take a look at this thread:
[Creating RTP Packets from Android Camera to Send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332532/creating-rtp-packets-from-android-camera-to-send/7333154#7333154)

**EDIT:**

found this great example project for RTP streaming: [SpyDroid](http://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/)

Answer (score 2):

Use [libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) library to stream video / audio RTP over UDP.

---

Or use [twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video) as ready solution ([hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)) already integrated, so you don't need to care about [STUN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN) / [TURN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traversal_Using_Relays_around_NAT) servers).

Answer (score -2):

With rtsp you should also specify the sdp file where the rtp and other info are stored.