# How to make Android device as RTSP server

Tags: android, android-ndk, rtsp, rtp, rtsp-client

I am curious to know if there is way that I can make my android device as a RTSP server and stream video with any other acceptable device. 
I have no understanding of RTSP server and other protocol that should be followed to make this happen.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
SKU

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make RTSP server at android phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512794/how-to-make-rtsp-server-at-android-phone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to worry about this problem. I seen a solution here 
http://techsplurge.com/5080/get-vlc-media-player-for-android-with-unofficial/ take read and get your answer.

Comment: The given link is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the architecture you should adopt is to put in place a remote machine. 
On this machine, you must have a server installed : Flash Media Server, Red5, etc. It will host the application that will get the coming stream and will outputs it.

Then, you can stream from a device (that you called "server") to the remote hosted application (ex: www.remoteserver.com:1234/myApp). To stream, just put that url in the input of a media container (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html). Hopefully, Android natively supports the RTSP protocol via that VideoView container.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I wanted my android device to run as rtsp server. A server which has some video content in it which will be streamed with other android device. For example - My Android device will have the video contents + RTSP server to stream the video and my friends device can run videoplayer (rtsp client) to stream the videos I have on my device. I think your suggestion is normal way rtsp server is setup.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to implement something similar. One suggestion I have received was, when you are making your device as RTSP server and someone wants to stream video from your device, its called peer to peer streaming. In this case, its better to involve a server in between, which acts like encoder-decoder. As in when another client sends RTSP SETUP request, it comes to your device for sure. But now when you are ready to stream video, send payload (using RTP) to server and server intern sends it to requesting device. You can avoid firewall problems possible in LAN or routers (in case of wife network).