# Writing the Android application which can access the camera and create the streaming video instated of storage

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtsp, android-mediacodec, android-mediarecorder

i can see some info abut the [rtsp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512794/how-to-make-rtsp-server-at-android-phone?rq=3)

But what i was looking is some [mediaCodec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec) API that i can use for my application.
So app will open the camera and start streaming, do we have API supported in android for streaming the video data ?

Comment: Have you seen this post: https://medium.com/@sandeepraghuraman/video-streaming-with-camerax-8549a0c86d21 ? It describes one of the ways to approach the problem.

Comment: @dev.bmax I will go through it.