# How to send RTP video packets from Android to server? Any library? please suggest

Tags: android, video, rtsp, rtp

I would like to put a video from the android device into RTP packets and then send them over UDP to a RTSP/RTP server.
Are there already some libraries in Android I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Well you got the `RTPStream` where as per the official documentation `RtpStream represents the base class of streams which send and receive network packets with media payloads over Real-time Transport Protocol (RTP).`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/RtpStream.html

then you want to take a look at the API demos as stated here: [Video streaming using RTSP: Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186950/video-streaming-using-rtsp-android) and see how the rtp/rtsp packet are made here: [Creating RTP Packets from Android Camera to Send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332532/creating-rtp-packets-from-android-camera-to-send)

Answer (score 1):

I have found that [spydroid](http://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/) is a good starting point.  It uses captures the encoded video from the MediaRecorder and sends it out over RTSP.

Comment: it sends using udp, which means you have to have your stream pre-setup  on media server.