# Sent and receive RTP streams in an Android application

Tags: android, audio-recording, rtp, audiorecord

I am currently building an Android application which should be able to sent and receive RTP streams using Android's `AudioRecord` API.

As I couldn't find any appriotate example, I am wondering if someone here already worked with RTP in an Android application? If so, what's the best way to get started? Are there already RTP libraries available which are compatible with the AudioRecord API?

Comment: [Maybe that helps you.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332532/creating-rtp-packets-from-android-camera-to-send)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an appropriate example, how RTP packets can be sent/received, in the [SipDroid](https://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/source/checkout) project.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/DeanThomson/android-udp-audio-chat) is a sample project to record audio and send it over a network based on UDP protocol.You can use this for reference.